# C program weird behaviour - pointer and memory

Tags: c, pointers, memory

I spent a few hours yesterday to find a bug in my program. I could break it down to the following. The code doesn't make much sense. But the problem is, that if I leave out the line

```
BST root2 = (BST) malloc(sizeof(BST));
```

in the function fillTree() the program does what it is supposed to. But uncommenting the line leads to the effect, that the data field of the BST root3 in fillTree() changes from NULL to something different.
But I don't understand why this is happening.

So uncommented I get the following output:

```
root3->data is still null!
```

But it should be (line commented):

```
root3->data is still null!
root3->data is still null!
root3->data is still null!
root3->data is still null!
```

Please help me!

Thank you very much!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct BSTTag{
  struct BSTTag* lNode;
  struct BSTTag* rNode;
  void *data;
  int (*compare)(void*, void*);
} *BST;


BST createTree(BST root) {
  if(root == NULL) {
    BST bst = (BST) malloc(sizeof(BST));
    bst->lNode = NULL;
    bst->rNode = NULL;
    bst->data = NULL;
    return bst;
  }
  return root;
}

BST fillTree(BST root, int n) {
  int i;
  BST root3 = NULL;
  // error occurrs if this line is not commented
  //BST root2 = (BST) malloc(sizeof(BST));
  for(i = n; i > 0; i--) {
    int *rd = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
    *rd = i;
    if(i == n) {
      root3 = createTree(NULL);
    }
    if(root3->data == NULL) {
      printf("root3->data is still null!\n");
    }
  }
  return root;
}

int main(void) {
  fillTree(NULL, 4);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You are allocating space only for a pointer,

```
BST bst = (BST) malloc(sizeof(BST));
```

but you use it as if you allocated space for the structure,

```
BST createTree(BST root) {
  if(root == NULL) {
    BST bst = (BST) malloc(sizeof(BST));
    bst->lNode = NULL;
    bst->rNode = NULL;
    bst->data = NULL;
    return bst;
  }
  return root;
}
```

and thus write past the allocated memory, invoking undefined behaviour.

You should allocate the proper size,

```
BST bst = (BST) malloc(sizeof(*bst));
```

Comment: So then you want to malloc (sizeof(BSTTag))

Comment: Yet another case of `typedef'ed pointers considered harmful` IMHO.

Comment: You're right! I did this the first time and I'm not going to make it any more^^